# Finding minimal distance between two curves using AM-GM inequality

Tags: calculus, optimization, contest-math, analytic-geometry, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Consider the following subsets of the plane: $C_{1}=\{(x,y)|x\gt 0,y=1/x\}$ and $C_{2}=\{(x,y)|x\lt 0,y=-1+1/x\}$ Given two points $P(x,y)$ and $Q(u,v)$ of the plane. Their distance $d(P,Q)$ is defined as:
> $$d(P,Q)=\sqrt{(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2}$$
> Show that there exists unique choice of $P_{0}\in C_{1}$ and $Q_{0}\in C_{2}$ such that $d(P_{0}, Q_{0})\le d(P,Q) \forall P \in C_{1}$ and $Q\in C_{2}$

---

**Attempted:**

Essentially all this problem asks for is to prove that there is a lower bound on the distance between the two subsets $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ of the plane and that, that minimal distance is achieved at unique $P_{0}$ and $Q_{0}$. To find the minimal distance, we can assert that, it has to be the length of the common normal. From the slopes of the two curves we can say, $P$ must be of the form $(x_{0},1/x_{0})$ and $Q$ of the form $(-x_{0},-1-1/x_{0})$. Now if we plug this into the expression for $d(P_{0},Q_{0})$, we get the following:

$$d(P_{0},Q_{0})=\sqrt{4x^2+1+\frac{4}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}}$$

To minimise we can set the derivative of $d^2(P_{0},Q_{0})$ with respect to  $x$ so get that $2x^4-x-2=0$ which has only one positive solution in $(1,2)$ by the intermediate value theorem, which also proves the uniqueness of the choice of $P_{0}$ and consequently $Q_{0}$. However if I try to apply the AM-GM inequality, and rewrite the expression inside the square root sign as follows, I do not get the condition of equality in which all terms should be equal:

$$x^2+x^2+x^2+x^2+\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x}\ge 10\cdot2^{1/5}$$

So how to go about it using the AM-GM inequality. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why must the x-coodinates be the same?

Comment: Setting $  1/ x_1 = -1 + 1/x_2$, and letting $ x_1 \rightarrow 0^+$, there is no minimum. The infimum is 0.

Comment: @ Calvin Lin- I agree with your first comment: it's not clear that the $x-$ coordinates will be the same. However for your second comment, look more closely at the definition of $C_2.$

Comment: At $P_0$ and $Q_0$ the tangents of the two curves should be orthogonal to the line $P_0Q_0$. Therefore the $x$-coordinates of the two points are negatives of each other. This leads to a quartic equation with expectedly nasty closed form solutions. Aided by Mathematica I got
$$x=-u\approx1.117349037$$ and the corresponding minimum
$$d^2\approx12.77770193.$$

Comment: Also, once we get uniqueness, we can deduce that $P_0Q_0$ should be symmetric around the point $(0,-\frac12)$, because one curve is a reflection of the other throught his point. This also tells us that the $x$-coordinates are negatives of each other.

Comment: A nice argument, @Misha! Anyway, from that orthogonality it follows that $x$ is the (unique) positive solution of the equation
$$2x^4=2+x.$$

Comment: I do get that quartic equation. However, I still do not understand why using the AM-GM inequality not hint at the value of $x$ at which minima is attained. The minimum, as per the inequality comes out to be $\approx 11.48698355$ which is less than the feasible minimum. Why is that so? What detail am I missing?

Comment: AM-GM has equality only when all the variables are equal. Surely it is impossible for all of $x^2, 2/x^2$ and $1/x$ to be equal to each other? In other words, in my humble opinion AM-GM is the wrong tool here. And sorry about missing it that you had that quartic already.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In principle, we can use weighted AM-GM to deal with that, rewriting $x^2 + \frac2{x^2} + \frac1x$ as $\delta_1(\frac{x^2}{\delta_1}) + \delta_2(\frac{2}{\delta_2 x^2}) + \delta_3 (\frac{1}{\delta_3 x})$. There's a whole theory of geometric programming which deals with finding the correct $\delta$'s to use. But for a one-variable problem, it will reduce to the same quartic equation in the end.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for clarifying. So it was the correct distribution of coefficients which I was missing out on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two coordinates are $(a,\frac1a)$ and $(-b,-1-\frac1b)$ for $a,b>0$, then the squared distance is $(a+b)^2 + (\frac1a + \frac1b + 1)^2$. We can make the substitution $a = e^u$ and $b = e^v$ to get the function
\begin{align}
f(u,v) &= (e^u + e^v)^2 + (e^{-u} + e^{-v} + 1)^2 \\
  &= 2 e^{-u-v}+2 e^{u+v}+e^{-2 u}+2 e^{-u}+e^{2 u}+e^{-2 v}+2 e^{-v}+e^{2 v}+1
\end{align}
which we optimize over all $u,v \in \mathbb R$.

This function is strictly convex, because each term is convex and some are strictly convex, which tells us that the minimizer (if it exists) is unique.

The minimum doesn't have to be achievable in general when optimizing a function over $\mathbb R^2$. However, we can argue that actually, $u,v \in [-2,2]$ (for instance), because $f(0,0)=13$, and one of the terms $e^{2u}, e^{2v}, e^{-2u}, e^{-2v}$ will exceed $13$ if $|u| > 2$ or $|v|>2$. So we can reduce the problem to minimizing $f$ over $[-2,2]^2$, and then a minimizer has to exist by the extreme value theorem.